# Can't access only one web server from only my house [solved]

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, virtualbox, dns

I was digging around in some settings the other day trying to set up a web server from a Virtual Machine on my computer. Somehow in doing this I managed to make it impossible to access my website, which is hosted externally. Only from my house though. I can access any other website from here, and access my website from any place but behind my own router.

I'm not *really* sure what the problem is, but I think it might be how I was setting up my VM. It's Ubuntu Server on a Windows 7 with VirtualBox. At some point it was asking me something about mail servers, and gave me some options including 'Internet site' which is what I chose, and put in my website's URL. This is the only time I can think of that I could have changed something, but I'm not really sure what happened or if this is it. Just my best guess.

I've already checked the firewall settings and the hosts file and the settings on my website to see if I accidentally IP blocked myself, but none of those attempts have worked. Been working on this for a few days now with no success... Any ideas?

We have an ASUS RT-AC66R, and a Cisco DPC3825 DOCSIS 3.0 Gateway.

Running nslookup shows

```
Server:  router.asus.com
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    example.com
Address:  104.152.168.19
Aliases:  www.example.com
```

Edit: So my dad fixed it. Apparently the gateway was in router mode and was supposed to be in bridge mode. Don't know if/how I changed it but that was the issue. It might have happened when it updated.

Comment: Please post the output of running the command `nslookup www.yoursitehere.com` from a Command Prompt on your Windows 7 machine. Replace your actual site with example.com in the posted output.